# How do you get the confidence level of a positive random variable, in the interval $[0,4]$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 0.2$

Tags: probability

We have a positive random variable $Y$, and with an expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 0.2$. We do not know the pdf, or standard deviation.
How do we get the confidence level in the interval $[0,4]$? (Estimate the probability that Y lands in $[0,4]$)
I'd prefer if the answer uses the $q$-function if possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you know expectation only, use Markov inequality.

Comment: @kludg okay, perfect! Thank you so much. I thought it was that, but u wasn't sure

Answer (score 0):

Like @kludg said, use Markov's inequality to solve this, so:
$P(Y$ in $[0,a]) = μ / a$ 
so: 
$P(Y$ in $[0,a]) = 0.2 / 4$